# How to use while loop in arduino for infinte loop

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am doing code of esp while switching hotspot for connecting esp i am getting some problem .
I am using this line of code:

```
while ((!esp.find("WIFI ")) || (!esp.find("+CWJAP:3")));
```

but it is not working. Anybody please give me alternate how to use this type of looping.

Comment: What exactly is "not working".  Can you explain?  Otherwise it is hard, if not impossible, to help.

Answer (score 2):

The `find` method reads the characters until the searched string is found or a timeout interval is passed.

In your case if the connection is not successful, **the first `find`** will not find "WIFI" and **will read all the input** including the "+CWJAP:3", then on timeout it returns false. The second `find` will wait until timeout and then return false.

Comment: so what i can do i have to wait until WIFI or +CWJAP=3 is come on serial monitor

Comment: read the lines returned by AT firmware into a buffer and compare the content of the buffer with expected strings. or use the WiFiEsp library, which handles the AT commands and responses for you